# Azure Web App doesn't build typescript files

Tags: asp.net, azure, typescript, asp.net-core, kudu

I have an ASP.NET Core project which has this structure:

```
- tsconfig.json
- app
 |- file1.ts
 |- file2.ts
 |- file3.ts
- wwwroot
 |- app
 |- index.html
```

tsconfig has these contents:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "amd",
    "outFile": "wwwroot/app/app.js",
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

When I try to deploy this project from git to Azure Web App my .ts files don't get compiled. I thought Kudu can deal with Typescript already. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you open an issue on https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu with a [minimal sample repo](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-git-repo-to-report-an-issue)? Thanks.

Comment: Conversation moved to https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David Ebbo said, conversation was moved to https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2156 and resolved there.